# How does require() work?

Tags: javascript, macos, react-native

I'm learning react-native and I'm facing a strange issue when requiring pictures for my app. I made a few tests and here's what I found :

```
// Not OK
path = "../imgs/banana.png"
require(path)

// OK
let path = "../imgs/banana.png"
require(path)

// Not OK
let path = "../imgs/" + this.props.fileName
require(path)
```

But I get the same error for to two cases not working with a 500 error code :

```
calls to 'require' expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: 'require(path)'
```

For the second one it founds `require(\"../imgs\" + this.props.fileName)`
But the value of path is correct : `../imgs/banana.png`

Why does it act like this ? Or am I missing something ?

How do you require multiples pictures without having to specify each of them in a switch case ?

Comment: In the title you should have "work" and no ''works"

Comment: Why do you want to `require` (embed as code) an image at all?!

Comment: To display them as showed in react-native official documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying you have to use string literals with `require`, not expressions.

In other words, you can't `require` things dynamically in that environment.

**EDIT:** If you know all the images in advance, you can shove the references to them in an object:

```
const images = {
  banana: require('banana.png'),
  apple: require('apple.png'),
  monkey: require('monkey.png'),
}
```

and use `{images.banana}` (or dynamically `{images[this.props.imageName]}`).

Comment: So basically even if `let path = "../imgs/banana.png"` and `let path = "../imgs/" + this.props.fileName` returns the exact same string, it's not a string literal  ? I'm a bit confused on this

Comment: Yes. One is a string literal, like `'hello'`, the other is an expression (`'hel' + 'lo'`). Consider, say, the number 17050. You could represent it as `50 * 341`, for instance, but one's a constant literal, the other takes effort to compute.

Comment: Ok but how do I get my images without manually specifying each path in a switch case ? I edit the post to precise the questions

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use dynamic strings like that:

```
let path = `../imgs/${this.props.fileName}`
```

You have to use different quotes.

Comment: That's not a string literal either. That's a template string.